# Set NavigationBar title on next ViewController without visual bugs

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a `UICollectionView` called `WeatherVC` that has a `NavigationController`.

`WeatherVC` segues to `WeatherDetailVC` which is `UITableView` upon `UICollectionViewCell` selection.

I want to set `WeatherDetailVC` NavigationBar title based on which `UICollectionViewCell` was selected.

This code below makes my whole NavigationBar just buggy.
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THxaZ.jpg

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? WeatherDetailVC {
      let cities = ["City1", "City2", "City3", "City4"]
      // cellPressed = 3 - for example this would work without bugs
      vc.navigationItem.title = cities[cellPressed]
    }
}
```

Variable `cellPressed` was set on cell highlight or tap. It behaves like this only in iOS 13 and only if I give it number based on cell tapped - if it is static, title changes with no visual bugs. I already tried creating functions inside `WeatherDetailVC` to change its title and calling them in `prepare for:segue` but it did not help whatsoever.

EDIT: My main problem is those bugs or glitches that comes with this solution. I have no problem with changing next VC title.

Comment: Share your sample code git hub link will solve your problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Since navigationBar title represents the title of the view controller, You can set it directly:

```
vc.title = cities[cellPressed]
```

<sub>Assuming `cities[cellPressed]` is tested and returning correct value</sub>

Comment: This and navigationItem.title changes my title no problem but visual glitches still occurs and this is my main problem. I already edited my post if it was not clear, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It happens because of the diacritic. If I assign title with diacritic character navigation bar just bugs everytime. Anyone know how to fix it?

EDIT: You can see this happening in IMGUR link that I provided. Character "á" is in the title.